# Can you use "еще там" like "тоже" when enumerating things?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> X. Ну и Y тоже. Ну и Z, да. **Вино еще там... А!**

Context: A man asks his wife on the phone to tell him what she wants him to buy for dinner, and she enumerates several items, as they occur to her, one after another.

I wonder if this entire phrase means:

> And wine, too... Yeah!

- "еще" = another addition
- "там" = to/in the list

Comment: I would say that `там` in this case is not "there, in the list", but a filler word, such as "like". So, it's rather "and also wine and what not".

Comment: To answer your question - Yes. But "еще там" is rather colloquial.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I think this comment deserves to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's shortened from full sentence (развёрнутого предложения): ещё там должно было быть. „Ну и“ at the beginning it's marker that person remind sth, or specifies. 
Like: ещё там можно было кататься на велосипеде. Ну и на скейте тоже.